# How to download/save a LinkedIn profile as a PDF file using Java?

Tags: java, rest, api, jsoup, linkedin-api

I have a list of URLs to LinkedIn profiles and I would like to download/save all of them as PDF files using Java. So far, I have managed to download the html version of the profiles, which cannot even be opened using browsers for some reason. I have used the **JSoup** library and this is the code I got:

```
public static void main(String arg [])
{
    try {

        String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document responseDocument = response.parse();
        Element loginCsrfParam = responseDocument
                .select("input[name=loginCsrfParam]")
                .first();

        response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .data("loginCsrfParam", loginCsrfParam.attr("value"))
                .data("session_key", "user@name.com")
                .data("session_password", "aPassWord")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();

        Connection.Response aResponse = Jsoup.connect("ProfileURL").cookies(response.cookies()).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
        Document aResponseDocument = aResponse.parse();

        try
        {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:/Users/userName/Desktop/DownLoadedProfile.html", false);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            bufferedWriter.write(aResponseDocument.getAllElements().toString());
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**If possible, how can I extend this code to invoke the (Save to PDF) option and download the profile?**

Comment: You may need to actually implement it.

Comment: @lexicore A hint to the right direction would be deeply appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

You can use some free java library that can convert html to pdf for example jPDFWriter. Here is example :

```
import com.qoppa.pdfWriter.PDFDocument;
...
File f1 = new File ("c:/htmlsamplepage.html");
pdfDoc = PDFDocument.loadHTML(f1.toURI().toURL(), new PageFormat (), false);
pdfDoc.saveDocument ("c:\\output.pdf");
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to be logged in to access the profiles. I don't think it is possible to do so using jPDFWriter, is it?

Comment: No, i don't think. jPDFWriter is a library that allow you to convert html to the pdf. You added code that save LinkedIn profile to the html. Assuming that your code works fine you can add some class that would be responsible for converting html to pdf.